# Multiple Assemblies for Multiple Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

I'm not sure how to organize my project. I have a solution with multiple services. eg. ShoppingCart, UrlShortener. The AppHostBase can only take one assembly however. I'm also interested in separation of concerns and in future use cases if separating Interface assemblies from ServiceModel assemblies. Should my domain model need to know about the interface (perhaps client requirements?) then at least the namespace won't get flooded with unnecessary DTO's etc.

So right now I see it as such, each being separate assemblies/projects:

```
MyApp.RestServices.ShoppingCartService.Interface
MyApp.RestServices.ShoppingCartService.ServiceModel
MyApp.RestServices.UrlShorteningService.Interface
MyApp.RestServices.UrlShorteningService.ServiceModel
```

I'm confused in the fact that when registering the AppHost you can only configure one Assembly.

```
public AppHost() : base("MyApp's REST services", 
    typeof(MyApp.RestServices.ShoppingCartService.Interface).Assembly) {}
```

In my case I want separate assemblies for different services, eg. Short Url Service, Shopping Cart Service.  I don't want to have to put them all in one project.

```
public AppHost() : base("MyApp's REST services", 
    new[]{
          typeof(MyApp.RestServices.ShoppingCartService.Interface).Assembly,
          typeof(MyApp.RestServices.Interface.ShoppingCartService).Assembly}
) {}
```

I'm really quite new so there is a lot I can be missing but I do wish to get it right for the long term as I continue to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ServiceStack accepts a `params Assembly[]` in the [AppHostBase constructor](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/AppHostBase.cs#L27), i.e:

```
protected AppHostBase(
    string serviceName, params Assembly[] assembliesWithServices) {...}
```

Which means you can tell ServiceStack to scan multiple assemblies with:

```
public AppHost() : base("MyApp's REST services", 
      typeof(MyApp.RestServices.ShoppingCartService.Interface).Assembly,
      typeof(MyApp.RestServices.Interface.ShoppingCartService).Assembly) {...}
```